# Potencial duplicates component on Communities

Tags: community, lightning-community, duplicate-management

Is it possible to add the Potencial duplicates component to Lightning Communities?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any component provided by salesforce out of the box that can be added to the communities. You might want to try [CloudAnswers Potential Duplicates Component](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcyysUAB) appexchange package.

I have tried this package in my Dev org community and can see a custom component available in community builder
[image: component after package is installed]
[image]